# Toggle Axes/Grid in p5.js "below" a drawing

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm currently experimenting with generative art/creative coding. I'm using p5.js to generate some ellipses following a invisible circle, which I can adjust with some controls (changing scale, direction and so on...).

[UI without axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1tNB.jpg)

Now I want to add some functionality to toggle some axes/grid etc like this:

[UI with axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvIcQ.jpg)

I know, that p5.js draws 60 times per second and that I could redraw everything every frame (which I think I could achieve by storing all ellipses etc and redraw them every frame, but to me this seems like a bad practice, because I would have to store a lot of information just for redrawing some "metadrawings").

So my question is: How can I toggle axes/grid without storing the whole drawing in a perfomant way? My first thought was to use two up to N canvases for "metadrawing" like axes, grid and so on and clear or redraw them, if I toggle them.

Answer (score 1):

I've kinda managed it now to solve my problem (other recommendations using best practices welcome! :) ).

I've added three div's (one wrapper for meta drawings, one wrapper for the main drawings and one wrapper for the two other wrappers). Then I just place the main-drawing-wrapper above my meta-drawing-wrapper using css. I'm also using p5.js instance mode to have separate sketches.

HTML:

```
<div id="drawings-wrapper">
    <div id="meta-drawing-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div id="main-drawing-wrapper">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#drawings-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}

#meta-drawing-wrapper, #main-drawing-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}

#meta-drawing-wrapper {
    z-index: 0;
}

#main-drawing-wrapper {
    z-index: 10
}
```

JS:

```
new p5((sketch) => {...} // meta drawing

new p5((sketch) => {...} // main drawing
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Another option would be using different 'layers' via [`p5.Graphics/createGraphics()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics). Have a look at the example, you could 'cache' your drawing and simply display using `image()` and re-render as needed when there's an update.